# All of my tags from WeedlLon's paid rig are missing when I reopen the project

Tags: software, cinema4d

Okay so for some of you that may not know, there is a YouTuber named weedlion. He does minecraft advanced rigs and such. So I bought his advanced rig with moving teeth, a moving mouth, moving eyebrows, moving eys and such. So I bought his rig, in the right there are the tags. When I insert the rig into cinema 4d the tags come up great. They work fine (btw the tags, when I double click comes up in a new window and I can click on the picture and and select what body parts I want to move and such. But when I save it, close out, and reopen, the tags are gone. I can still open the window, but either way the tags are not there. Can someone help me figure out what's happening so I can import that rig into another project?

Answer (score 1):

Open the project that you want to insert the rig into.  Open the rig by using the "Merge" command under the file menu instead of the usual "Open" command.  This will place a copy of the content in the project upon which you are currently working.  For help with disappearing controls, I'd have to actually see the rig and how you're using it to know what's going on.  It sounds like maybe the HUD elements are only set to display under certain circumstances.  You can change this behavior by right-clicking on any HUD element and changing it's settings, but again, I'm only guessing that this might be your issue.  Any way you could upload some screenshots, or better yet, a video of how you're using the rig?  I could modify my answer to be more helpful.

*edit  I think the tag you're talking about is the Visual Selector Tool.  I found a video that might be helpful to you.